# Loop for stacking time (C#, Unity)

Tags: c#, unityscript

I'd like to count time to 10 seconds, then make countToTen = 0 and start the loop again until it reaches 10 again. For now, Unity is crushing and I don't know why.

Can you help me?

```
public float countToTen;    
void Update(){
       do{
            if(countToTen<=10){
               countToTen=(int)(Time.time%60f);
            }
        }
        while(countToTen<=10);}
```

Comment: What is the value of `Time.time`? I imagine the modulo of that is making this get stuck in an infinite loop. You should let your game use its own loop and then just reset the count back to 0 whenever it gets over its threshold. You can then increment it periodically

Comment: Have you tagged this question correctly? Note that the [tag:unity] tag *isn't* for the Unity game engine, which I suspect is what you were aiming for.

Comment: A general comment - no need to use a do while loop if your do is governed by the same condition as the while. Just use while (countToTen <= 10)...

Answer (score 0):

that's not the right way to do it. I mean, you CAN do it but you're using a chisel when you have a sledghammer.

```
IEnumerator myFunction( float s )
{
    Debug.log ("waiting...");
    yield return new waitForSeconds(s);
    Debug.log("tada!");
}

//call me on onclick or whenever, but not in update() ^^
void startFunction() 
{
    StartCoroutine(myFunction( 10));
}

void update()
{

}
```

Comment: Maybe I wasn't precise enough. I have one script, which is showing a text line on a screen. In another script (the one in my first post) I have a timer, which counts seconds and minutes and shows it on a GUI. My idea was to show a text on a screen every 10 seconds, and to check if it a loop is working as I wanted, I put it in Update().

Comment: that's the wrong pattern: I strongly suggest you pickup a C# book before continuing on your game, or you'll end up in a lot of spaghetti code, it's a very natural impulse to use update for that but believe me, it's wrong. In your case, just have a coroutine do what you want to do every 10 seconds, and the other one in your script calling it on Start(). You can then use the preferred method to control the first script (via sendmessage or via variables or whatever). Do not use update and count Time.deltatime to do timers, it'll end up messing up your code.

Comment: Thanks for that notice. I am using timer in Update right now only for developing purposes. Later, I will delete this code. it is only for me, to see if other scripts (whch will be used now with coroutine!) work correctly. I never knew that there is something like coroutine, now my life will be much easier.

Comment: you're welcome! coroutines are very powerful, remember you can also stop a coroutine with StopCoroutine()!

Answer (score 0):

That loop will block the update as the time won't change until your update funciton finishes executing. Instead, I guess what you want to do is count to 10 seconds then do something, then wait another 10 seconds.

The Unity way of doing that is with a [co-routine](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html). Basically, you do something like:

```
IEnumerator WaitThenDoSomething(float WaitTime) {
    while(running) 
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(WaitTime);
        DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Where `DoSomething()` is a function that will get executed every 10 seconds until `running` is set to false. You can start this running with the following code in your `Start()` method:

```
StartCoroutine(WaitThenDoSomething(10.0));
```

Comment: Works perfect. Thank you very much. And I really need to buy a book with C# basics;)      I am posting the code in a comment to my question.

Answer (score 0):

This is it, working perfectly. Thank you guys for helping me.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class TextReadFromFile : MonoBehaviour {

    GameObject player;
    public TextAsset wordFile;                                // Text file (assigned from Editor)
    private List<string> lineList = new List<string>();        // List to hold all the lines read from the text file
    Text text;
    Timer timer;
    PlayerHealth playerHealth;

    void Awake ()
    {
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Player");
        playerHealth = player.GetComponent <PlayerHealth>();
        text = GetComponent <Text>();
    }
    void Start()
    {
        ReadWordList();
        Debug.Log("Random line from list: " + GetRandomLine());

        StartCoroutine (Count(2.0f));

        }

    public void ReadWordList()
    {
        // Check if file exists before reading
        if (wordFile)
        {
            string line;
            StringReader textStream = new StringReader(wordFile.text);

            while((line = textStream.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                // Read each line from text file and add into list
                lineList.Add(line);
            }

            textStream.Close();
        }
    }

    public string GetRandomLine()
    {
        // Returns random line from list
        return lineList[Random.Range(0, lineList.Count)];
    }

    IEnumerator Count(float WaitTime){

        while(playerHealth.currentHealth >= 0)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(WaitTime);
            text.text = GetRandomLine();
        }
}


}
```